# How much of an aperiodic tiling is needed to force aperiodicity?

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, tiling, aperiodic-tiling

Consider an aperiodic tiling. By definition, there is a $C$ such that, for any box of side $C$, the part of the tiling contained in the box can be continued to the whole plane only in a non-periodic fashion.

Question: given an aperiodic tiling and given a box, how does one determine whether this is the case?

For concreteness<sup>(*)</sup>,
consider the Ammann-Beenker A5 tiling. How can I tell whether, say, the following pattern can be continued peridocally to the entire plane?

[image]

If not, is the "irregularity" in the upper right corner the only reason?

An algorithm would be a valid answer - and so would be an explanation.

<sub><sup>(*) and because I have a bathroom wall to tile. Nothing wrong with a real-world application...</sup></sub>

Comment: Yes, sorry, lapsus.

Comment: If you consider only tilings using two kinds of rhombs, maybe your question could be addressed using the fact that a rhombic Penrose tiling is determined by its so called *1-atlas* ? See https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.08239.pdf

Comment: I don't think this is actually true "by definition"? An aperiodic tiling is just a tiling that isn't periodic; there's no requirement that a given finite subset of it has no periodic continuation, and indeed I don't actually see why this ought to be true about e.g. the A5 tiling.

Comment: Well, it's true by one of the definitions, and I think the A5 tiling satisfies, no? Aperiodic != nonperiodic.

Answer (score 2):

While your question does not specify all details, in general it follows from the [undecidability of the Domino problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile#Domino_problem) that this is also undecidable. In fact, your problem seems slightly easier, as if you already start a tiling, we can assume that a 'START' domino is present. Then if the respective Turing-machine doesn't halt from a given starting position, it can be easily modified to give an aperiodic tiling, while if it halts, then you can make some big bounding box around it, and repeat this box in any periodic way.

I know I haven't provided much details in this answer, but all this is quite standard textbook material.
Also note that this answer doesn't say anything about the Ammann-Beenker A5 tiling, but by the existence of universal Turing-machines, there is a fixed set of tiles for which the problem is undecidable.

Comment: ... but that doesn't preclude a practical algorithm that usually works from existing in general, let alone for this tiling.

Comment: Yes, there might of course be methods that work in special cases.

Comment: There's a chance I'm confused here, but I think the statement "by the existence of universal Turing-machines, there is a fixed set of tiles for which the problem is undecidable" is not quite right. The way it was explained to me, any SINGLE true-false statement is trivially algorithmically undecidable; it's either true or false, and either way, there is an algorithm which returns that answer.

The question of algorithmic undecidability is only meaningful for a function f(n) from an infinite set to {true, false}, and means that there cannot exist an algorithm which, on input n, returns f(n).

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should have phrased that differently.